# how do I import a contract in remix

Tags: solidity

[image]

I am using the import function to add a contract to my contract. For some reason I keep getting this error that it is not found and I am not sure why.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with git or github

Comment: Don't emote, just state the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

Simple Storage and Storage Factory Solidity files must be at the same folder level.